# Java: Using Class.forName to dynamically get a new instance of itself

Tags: java, reflection

Lets say I have a class named  Dog which is a subclass of Animal

I have a method that needs to create an instance of a specific subclass of animal based on a string  parameter

```
public void createAnimalType(String animalType) {

Class clazz = Class.forName(animalType);

//Check if animalType  equals Dog, or Cat, or Fox, etc
// Example
Dog dog = (Dog) clazz.newInstance();
...
```

Is there a way to crate an instance of itself (Dog, Cat, etc, Not of type Animal) without using an explicit cast to the Subclass (Dog)in this case?

I may be missing a finer point of polymorphism (as in why do I  want to do that . .  should be casting it to Object or Anmial :-) )

Thanks for helping me get smart on this.

Comment: The most important point is that downcasting has no relevance to the object type. Downcasting only allows you to put something that the compiler saw as an Object (e.g. the result of `newInstance`) into a variable of type Dog. The thing you put in the variable must already be a Dog -- and this was decided in the line above, `Class.forName("Dog");` I think you might be asking something subtly different, but don't yet see what.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If there is a no-args contructor, you can use `getClass().newInstance()`.

`getClass()` when used in a superclass will give you the actual class of `this`, for example `Dog` in your example.

Your whole method would become:

```
public Animal createAnimal() {
    return getClass().newInstance();
}
```

Comment: brilliant. I  got it to work like this . . .  Animal myNoCastActualAnimal = (Animal) clazz.newInstance(); myNoCastActualAnimal.createAnimal();