# How to get class Object by using class Name at runtime in java

Tags: java, reflection

I am working on java,In run time I got class name but I want to create object for that class how can I do this any one help  me.
I tried below way please check my code below.

```
String emp = "Emp" // this is the classname i got in runtime(I will get dynamical this name)
Object obj = class.forName().newInstance();
```

up to this it is working fine ,but I got java.lang.Object in above code I don't want that object I want to convert that object into my className(Emp)object.
   like

```
Emp e =(Emp)obj;
```

**Note:** I am not sure every time I will get Emp classname at runtime total I have 100 Classes in myproject so any classname I will get here(like Emp,Dept,Student.....).

Comment: Reflection is your friend

Comment: are you wanting to use singletons ?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10258245/java-using-class-forname-to-dynamically-get-a-new-instance-of-itself

Comment: provide more information about the code. Where and how are you using `Emp e =(Emp)obj;` in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I don't understand your question, but if you are looking to create a class instance only using your class name, you can try this method:

```
public static MyClass getFromString(String myClassName) {
     Object result = null;
     MyClass final_result = null;

     try{
         result = Class.forName(myClassName).getConstructor().newInstance();
         final_result= (MyClass)result;
     }catch(ClassNotFoundException e){} //you must specify concrete Exception here

     return final_result; 
    }
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

It’s not clear what you are trying to achieve. If you are confident that the class you loaded dynamically is `Emp` (or a subclass of it) it is sufficient to do the type cast like you did in your question. If you have doubts about the dynamically loaded type being compatible with `Emp`, because of the one hundred other classes you have, then it’s not clear what you expect from us.

What you can do is to separate the type checking from the instantiation, e.g.

```
Class<? extends Emp> type = Class.forName(className).asSubclass(Emp.class);

Emp instance = type.newInstance();
```

This checks whether the type is compatible with `Emp` in the first line, thus the second line is guaranteed to return an instance of `Emp`.

However, the way, an incompatible type is reported does not change. It will be done by throwing a `ClassCastException`.

If that’s not what you were asking for, you should reword your question.

Comment: how can you say `Emp.class`? you have just a string of class name

Comment: @user3218114: that’s why I said, it’s unclear what the questions is about. If `Emp` is known it compile time, a simple type cast like already written in the question will do as well. If it’s not, then you can’t have a variable of type `Emp` so what does the questioner actually want?

Comment: I think OP wants object of the exact type as the class name but that's not possible. return `Emp` if class name is "Emp" and return `Student` if class name is "student" etc.

Comment: @user3218114: the objects *have* the exact type as the class name. It’s only the compile-time type of the reference variable which doesn’t match. And that is irrelevant for the runtime-behavior of a Java program. And, well, you can’t have a variable with a compile-time type of a type not available at compile-time. But it’s not clear whether that really needs to be explained…

Answer (score -1):

```
Object object=Class.forName(className).getConstructor().newInstance();
```

Comment: The return type should be `Emp` not `Object` as per OP's requirement

Answer (score -1):

```
  // Complete class name, including Package
  String name = "com.foo.Emp";

  Object object = Class.forName(name).getConstructor().newInstance();
  if (object instanceof Emp) {
     // Specific logic for Emp objects
  } else if (object instanceof Dept) {
     // Specific logic for Dept objects
  }
```

Hope it helps you

Comment: what about 100 other classes as OP mentioned in the post

Comment: Upps, sorry man. I didn't read your reference to tthe 100 classes. Auto flag for me